# Scala Pattern Matching :+ +: operator

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I'm confused about the :+ and +: operators in Scala pattern matching.

I have the following function which should return the last value in a list

```
object Solution {

    def last[A](seq: Seq[A]) : A = seq match {
        case head +: Nil => head
        case head +: tail => last(tail)
    }

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        println("1: " + last(List(1, 2, 3, 4)))
    }
}
```

But I receive some errors when running the code

```
error: not found: value +:
error: not found: value head
error: not found: value +:
error: not found: value tail
```

What am I missing here?

EDIT: I'm running this with Scala 2.9.2

Comment: it should be "case head :: Nil => …"

Comment: the code you posted works for me

Comment: @EugeneZhulenev No, `::` is only for `List`. `+:` is needed for `Seq`.

Comment: @0__ What version of Scala are you running?

Comment: Bumping, because extractors are a little strange -- see the comments -- especially at first.  I hope this makes the downvoter think twice.  of course, by "research effort," we're not talking Ph D research.  But even if you know how to locate the scaladoc, you may not know what to search for.  PS) Pity those stuck on 2.9.2 for whatever reason.

Comment: @som-snytt I'm only on it because the xubuntu repository hasn't been updated yet.

Comment: @user3277752 If you install sbt (`apt-get install sbt`), create a build.sbt file with `scalaVersion = 2.11.0`, and run `sbt console`, it will download 2.11 and start a 2.11 REPL for you.  Add your dependencies to build.sbt and sbt console will download them -- and *their* dependencies -- and put them on the classpath for you.  Running the REPL from sbt is *way* easier than downloading Scala and your dependencies and their dependencies and setting up the classpath manually!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extractors are objects, so you want to look up `+:`.

On 2.11,

```
scala> +:
res0: collection.+:.type = scala.collection.$plus$colon$@5f2050f6
```

But compare

[http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.0/#scala.collection.$plus$colon$](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.0/#scala.collection.%24plus%24colon%24)

with

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.2/#scala.collection.package

where there is no such extractor.